# C++ comparator override

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

Suppose I have a Base class, and multiple derived class(could be more in the future).
Is there a way to override comparator of derived classed, or achieving the same result?

```
class Base {
 public:
  virtual bool operator==(const Base&) = 0;
};

class Version1 : public Base {
 public:
  bool operator==(const Derived&) {
    // do something
  }
};

class Version2 : public Base {
 public:
  bool operator==(const Derived&) {
    // do something
  }
};

// Could be more version derived class


int main() {
  Base *obj1 = new Version1;
  Base *obj2 = new Version1;
  std::cout << (*obj1 == *obj2) << std::endl;  // is there a way to do so?
}
```

Specifically, any subclass of `Base` be comparable to any other subclass of `Base` without macro and dynamic_cast.

Comment: Should those uses of `Derived` in `operator==` actually be `Version1` and `Version2` respectively? Because you don't have anything named `Derived`...

Comment: And to be clear, is your intent that any subclass of `Base` be comparable to any other subclass of `Base`, vs. a specific subclass being comparable to other instances of that subclass, but not other subclasses of `Base` that aren't direct ancestors or descendants? Because that pure virtual declaration is saying any `Base` subclass must be comparable to any other `Base` subclass, even if they're different classes, using only the features available from `Base`, which is a weird requirement to impose.

Comment: Any subclass of Base be comparable to any other subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, C++ does not support multi-dynamic dispatch, so there's no way to do this directly -- you end up needing to use dynamic_cast and extra checking in the comparison function:

```
class Base {
 public:
    virtual bool operator==(const Base&) const = 0;
};

class Version1 : public Base {
 public:
    bool operator==(const Base &b) const {
        if (auto *a = dynamic_cast<Version1 *>(&b)) {
            if (typeid(*this) != typeid(*a)) {
                // `a` is some other class derived from Version1
                return false; }
            // compare fields of *this and *a for equality
            return f1 == a->f1 && f2 == a->f2 && ...
        }
        return false;
    }
```

one tricky part is the `typeid` test, which is only needed if there might be some other class(es) derived from Version1 in the future.  If it is final (`class Version1 final : public Base`...) then the typeid test is not needed.

Another detail is the `const` on the `operator==` functions -- you almost always want that so you can compare (with) rvalues or constants.

Comment: Ah that's what my program looks like now... Since there're too many function calls, I'm wondering if it's possible to replace them with if/else branch.

Comment: What do you mean by "too many function calls"?  Too hard to read/understand/maintain the code?  Too slow?  If/else branches are generally slower than function calls.

Comment: There're around 10 versions of derived class. Everytime I do comparison I did something like 
``
if (v1 == version1 && v2 == version1) {}
else if (v1 == version1 && v2 == version2) {} 
``

Comment: Not sure why you have lots of comparisons, unless you are comparing lots of different objects?  But that doesn't seem to have any connection to your question.

Comment: Yes, every version of objects should be comparable to each other. And comparator includes ==, <, >, etc

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will do what you want, but you can do:

```
class Version1 : public Base {
 public:
  bool operator==(const Base&) {
    // do something
  }
};
```

and

```
class Version2 : public Base {
 public:
  bool operator==(const Base&) {
    // do something
  }
};
```

This ensures that `version1` and `version2` are not abstract classes and can therefore be instantiated.

---

Well, now that we know what the real problem is, I can attempt a better answer.  The desired 'double dispatch' can be simulated by adding another virtual function, let's call it `TaggedEquals`, and calling it with the parameters reversed, along with an `enum` identifying the type of the object being passed.  This gets us into a situation where a simple `switch` statement in `TaggedEquals` will complete the job.

Here is some code to demonstrate what I am talking about:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual bool operator== (const Base& other) = 0;

    enum ParamType { D1, D2 };
    virtual bool TaggedEquals (const Base& other, enum ParamType paramtype) const = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    bool operator== (const Base& other) override
    {
        return other.TaggedEquals (*this, D1);
    }
    
private:
    bool TaggedEquals (const Base&, enum ParamType paramtype) const override
    {
        switch (paramtype)
        {
            case D1:
                std::cout << "D1 == D1\n";
                return true;
            case D2:
                std::cout << "D2 == D1\n";
                return false;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    bool operator== (const Base& other) override
    {
        return other.TaggedEquals (*this, D2);
    }

private:
    bool TaggedEquals (const Base&, enum ParamType paramtype) const override
    {
        switch (paramtype)
        {
            case D1:
                std::cout << "D1 == D2\n";
                return false;
            case D2:
                std::cout << "D2 == D2\n";
                return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *d1a = new Derived1;
    Base *d1b = new Derived1;
    std::cout << (*d1a == *d1b) << "\n";
    Base *d2 = new Derived2;
    std::cout << (*d1a == *d2) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
D1 == D1
1
D1 == D2
0
```

This approach has the advantage that if you add a value to your `enum`, the compiler will remind you to add it to your `switch` statements.

To implement something like `operator<`, you will need something like `TaggedGreaterThanOrEqualTo` (since you swap the parameters round), or you could emulate that with `TaggedGreaterThan` and `TaggedEquals`.

Comment: Well, I don't think that works for my case. I definitely need a comparison between two Base*, without ugly dynamic_cast every time.

Comment: [I tested it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/db4fKrAeiIFF1bKO), it seems to work.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I also want version1 == version1, which won't be decided as version1 == Base

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment.

Comment: In your code snippet, I want obj1 and obj2 match the operator with signature `Version1::operator==(const Version1&)`. Your implementation will guide the compile to invoke `Version1::operator(const Base&)`.

Comment: Why?  You can't instantiate `Base`, and it's not clear what the code should do when comparing two different derived classes.

Comment: Because in your code, you're actually calling `obj1->operator==(Base)`

Answer (score 0):

Double dispatch works.

```
// Forward declaration
class Version1;

class Base {
 public:
  virtual bool operator==(const Base&) const = 0;
  virtual bool operator==(const Version1&) const = 0;
};

class Version1 : public Base {
 public:
  bool operator==(const Base& rhs) const override {
    return rhs == *this;
  }
  
  bool operator==(const Version1& rhs) const override {
    std::cout << "Version1 / Version1\n";
    return true;
  }
};


int main() {
  Base *obj1 = new Version1;
  Base *obj2 = new Version1;
  std::cout << (*obj1 == *obj2) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an external template comparator operator between classes of the same interface

```
template<typename A, typename B>
bool operator==(const A& a, const B& b)
{
  static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Base, A>, "class must derive from A");
  static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Base, B>, "class must derive from B");

  // do your comparison
}
```